# regex match whole line instead of between the tag

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex and just testing it out, my problem is after looking at examples my regex is matching the whole line almost instead of in between the tag.

```
re.findall(r'<i>(.*)</i>', 'test <i>abc</i> <i>def</i>')

['abc</i> <i>def']
```

Why is it not matching just between the tags given me `abc` `def`

Comment: For testing it out, this is fine. If you really want to parse HTML with regular expression, please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `.*` which is greedy. You want to add `?` to the end of that making it  non greedy.

```
>>> re.findall(r'<i>(.*?)</i>', 'test <i>abc</i> <i>def</i>')
['abc', 'def']
```

From the `re` documentation:

> The `*`, `+`, and `?` qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE `<.>` is matched against `'<H1>title</H1>'`, it will match the entire string, and not just ''. Adding `?` after the qualifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as possible will be matched. Using `.?` in the previous expression will match only ''.

Comment: @fscore [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).  Good luck.